# Functions are not valid as a React child when i wrap a component in render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got this error when i wrap a component in render.

> Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

Here's my code in `index.js`

```
const aa = DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(<Provider store={store}>
<Container />
</Provider>);
ReactDOM.render(
  aa,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: returns another React component. @BhojendraRauniyar

Answer (score 2):

It should be like this:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>App</div>;
  }
}
const WrappedApp = DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(App)

const aa = <Provider store={store}>
              <WrappedApp />
           </Provider>

ReactDOM.render(
  aa,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

According to the error:

> Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

And the specification of the [DropDropContext](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs-drag-drop-context.html), then it's a function and..

> DragDropContext wraps your component and returns another React
>   component.

That makes sense. Well then, we will invoke that function first, to receive the *wrapped component*:

```
const WrappedApp = DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(App)
```

Then we continue to wrap that *wrapped component* with the `Provider`.

```
const aa = <Provider store={store}>
              <WrappedApp />
           </Provider>
```

And then using it

```
ReactDOM.render(
  aa,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

This is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/53zm08m5pn

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping

```
<Provider store={store}>
   <Container />
</Provider>)
```

within an App element and pass App as

```
DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(App)
```

Have a look at

[React DnD Docs](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs-drag-drop-context.html)